# Safari extension for Google results navigation (↑/k, ↓/j)

Tags: keyboard, google, safari-extensions, vi, navigation

Title says it all. I found some posts linking to some private locations (mostly dead). I wonder if there ain't something like that for Safari. Google Chrome has several of them. E.g. [Web Search Navigator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-search-navigator/cohamjploocgoejdfanacfgkhjkhdkek). Are these extensions just well hidden or aren't there any at all?

Answer (score 1):

I am also very annoyed by this. I found an old extension that isn't supported anymore called Mafuyu (http://wakabamac.blog95.fc2.com/blog-entry-1013.html). I've tried to run it but it's obsolete.

Another option seemed to be knogs which I found on GitHub (https://github.com/nqzero/knogs), originally for Chrome and Firefox but apparently someone adapted it for Safari. However, I have been unable to find the version for Safari because the only link i found was broken. (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90126/GoogleJK/GoogleJK.safariextz)

If someone found the solution to this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.